# Could not decode json type in spring cloud stream DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We are using spring-cloud-stream and planning to upgrade our Kafka version.
Our applications using `spring-cloud-stream:2.0.0` (spring-kafka 2.1.7) with apache kafka server `1.0.1`
and also using `spring-cloud-sleuth:2.0.0` for tracking.
We are going to upgrade our Kafka server to version `2.3.0` so it requires an upgrade to `spring-boot 2.2.x (Hoxton)` with `spring-cloud-sleuth:2.2.0` and `spring-cloud-stream:3.0.3 (Horsham.SR3)`.
We have ~200 applications that using Kafka hence the upgrade will be gradually, so as intermediate state we are going to have *producers* on the newer version and *consumers* using old version.
Our consumers are using `@StreamListener`.

During our tests we encountered an issue with parsing most of the headers with type `String` and getting the following:

```
ERROR 27448 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$4  : Could not decode json type: ecb89ccb3e79418b for key: X-B3-TraceId
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'ecb89ccb3e79418b': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"ecb89ccb3e79418b"; line: 1, column: 33]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:679) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3526) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2621) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:826) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:723) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3091) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.lambda$toHeaders$1(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:233) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.toHeaders(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:216) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$4.toHeaders(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:554) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.toMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:106) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
...
```

While the Types header is:

```
{spanTraceId=java.lang.String, spanId=java.lang.String, spanParentSpanId=java.lang.String, nativeHeaders=org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap, X-B3-SpanId=java.lang.String, X-B3-ParentSpanId=java.lang.String, scst_partition=java.lang.Integer, X-B3-Sampled=java.lang.String, X-B3-TraceId=java.lang.String, spanSampled=java.lang.String, contentType=java.lang.String}
```

For instance the `X-B3-SpanId` that was added by Sleuth is of type String and the value is: **ecb89ccb3e79418b** which is not JSON string, therefore the ObjectMapper **fails** on conversion to String Object here:

```
headers.put(h.key(), getObjectMapper().readValue(h.value(), type))
```

Looks like it should not use ObjectMapper when we have String types, hence our old consumers are failing.

Is there a way to prevent this issue when using new producer and old consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` to be compatible with older versions:

```java
    /**
     * Set to true to encode String-valued headers as JSON ("..."), by default just the
     * raw String value is converted to a byte array using the configured charset. Set to
     * true if a consumer of the outbound record is using Spring for Apache Kafka version
     * less than 2.3
     * @param encodeStrings true to encode (default false).
     * @since 2.3
     */
    public void setEncodeStrings(boolean encodeStrings) {
        this.encodeStrings = encodeStrings;
    }
```

Also see https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_binder_properties

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName`

Comment: Hi @gary , this suggestion isn't working. We've tried to produce using **Hoxton.SR3** with `encodeStrings flag = true` being set on the `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` as suggested.   With this setup the consumer is able to process all String headers but fails on content-type header. The type value of this header was changed to `org.springframework.util.MimeType` (due to the flag change) and the value is "application/json" hence it's trying to convert it to JSON and fails here: `headers.put(h.key(), getObjectMapper().readValue(h.value(), type));` with NPE.

Comment: Try using `BinderHeaderMapper` with the property set instead of `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper`; it was originally a clone but I see some additional code there to deal with `MimeType`.

Comment: Thanks @gary - `BinderHeaderMapper` did it, no other issues related to headers starting from `spring-kafka:2.3.7`